# my host shows java web files as raw files

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets, easyapache-4

so I bought a domain from bluehost that provide java web application according to their website.the problem is, my .jsp and .java files don't work probably, the .jsp files are displayed as raw text, How can I fix this?

ps: the cpanel uses easyapache4

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with easyapache.  But in a standard Apache httpd installation with Tomcat as your JSP engine, you'd need to have httpd configured to have `.jsp` files processed by Tomcat.  This is typically done by having the statement `JkMount /*.jsp ajp13` inside the `<VirtualHost>` element.  Sounds like you should be talking to bluehost's support to get this set up.

This resource may help if you are using Apache httpd and Tomcat - https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-3.3-doc/mod_jk-howto.html#s72

Comment: I asked more than 10 people in the support team of bluehost and they all tell me that they still didn't provide any technical support for the tomcat service. and for the link they are using mod_jk which was used in the easyApache 3 because now it isn't there. but thanks for the help

Comment: That Tomcat HOWTO link is from another century. You want http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/ or http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html.